# How can i use an image as a background in Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, settings

So I want to use an image as my background in Tkinter kind of like how windows has background images in desktop. This is my code but it doesn't seem to work:

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
background_image=tk.PhotoImage("image")
```

The code runs but it shows up as a white background.

Comment: Maybe this can help you https://youtu.be/WurCpmHtQc4

Comment: maybe it is because You do basically nothing with that image? You have to place that image somewhere too, like in a Label

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty simple! Here is how to do it:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")
bg = PhotoImage(file = "image.png")
label1 = Label(root, image = bg)
label1.place(x = 0, y = 0)
root.mainloop()
```

Just make sure to edit this part (file = "image.png") and use the pathname to your image. Preferably save it on the same folder as your program is stored, though it is not required.

Comment: how do i know the pathname?

Comment: If you are on a Mac, follow this [https://setapp.com/how-to/how-to-find-the-path-of-a-file-in-mac]. If you are on a Windows, follow these steps [https://www.howtogeek.com/670447/how-to-copy-the-full-path-of-a-file-on-windows-10/]